# cannot change root on nginx for some reason

Tags: nginx

For some reason I cannot change the root. I have the same rights as the default root on `/usr/share/nginx/html`, and I also have `755` recursive on all files and folders in my other folder. I even tried changing the user and group to root and nginx back and forth to see if it made any difference but it doesn't. I keep getting **403 Forbidden**

so basicly I made this folder

```
$ mkdir -p /srv/www/test.com/public_html

$ vi /srv/www/test.com/public_html/index.html

$ vi /srv/www/test.com/public_html/test.php

$ chmod -R 755 /srv/www/test.com/public_html
```

tried to change the user and group to nginx

```
$ chown -R nginx:nginx /srv/www
```

configured the main conf file

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

this is how my config looks like, the includes are commented out

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;   
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  _;
        root /srv/www/test.com/public_html;
        # root  /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
                autoindex on;
        }

        error_page  404 /404.html;

        location = /40x.html { }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html { }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

}
```

everything works in the default root folder that is commented out, but when I change the root
I get 403 forbidden. I feel like I have tried everything I can, changing users and file permissions
and so on. the php-fpm has nginx as user and group. and the user is set to nginx in the main.conf file. I only use this one file for configuration for nginx, and have the includes commented out.

I have no idea what to do. Been stuck for hours now. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's in your error log ? What's your test request ?

Comment: 2015/02/23 12:44:00 [error] 2869#0: *1 "/srv/www/test.com/public_html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.230, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.202"

Comment: What's the output of `ls -lh /srv/www/test.com/public_html/index.html` ? Do you have SELinux running enforcing mode ?

Comment: -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 91 Feb 23 11:15 /srv/www/test.com/public_html/index.html

Comment: i changed it all to root root like the default "root path"

Comment: $ namei -l /usr/share/nginx/html gives output

f: /usr/share/nginx/html
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root share
drwxr-xr-x root root nginx
drwxr-xr-x root root html

Comment: $ /usr/sbin/getenforce outputs Enforcing

Comment: So that's probably caused by SELinux. Does `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For clarity I'm posting my comment as answer, this was caused by SELinux and setting policy mode to permissive with `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` is one "*quick and dirty*" solution.

The clean solution would be to set the SELinux context `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /srv/www/test.com` and look for potential new SELinux complaints if any (depends on what you set next in your configuration file).

Comment: `restorecon` would work as well, since that's the default context for `/srv/www`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good point indeed.

Comment: thank you for the answer, sorry for not accepting answer, I didn't see it before now. thanks!